# using an underscore in a string

Tags: c, string

I tried to use an underscore inside of a string, but it seems to make the compiler allocate less bytes to the char array and run over the closing char ('\0').

what causing this?
is there a way to escape an underscore char?

Thanks.

for more information, see this code:

```
code:
#include<stdio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 6

char str_ex[][ARRSIZE] = {"aaaa", "bbbb_bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "ffff_ffff", "eeee"};

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++)
        printf("%s\n", str_ex[i]);
    return 0;
}

compile:
user@ubuntu:~/test$ gcc -g test.c -o test -Wall -ansi
test.c:4:1: warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]
test.c:4:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘str_ex[1]’) [enabled by default]
test.c:4:1: warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]
test.c:4:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘str_ex[4]’) [enabled by default]

output:
user@ubuntu:~/test$ ./test
aaaa
bbbb_bcccc
cccc
dddd
ffff_feeee
eeee
```

Comment: Welp. This doesn't do what you think it does. Also, underscores are barely erroneous. "This is a compiler bug" - well, it isn't.

Comment: (How on Earth did this get 2 upvotes?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `ARRSIZE` doesn't determine the size of the array but rather **the size of each individual subarray**. So you're telling it to store `bbbb_bbbb` in 6 chars. Maybe you could store pointers instead:

```
const char *str_ex[] = {....};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not because of the underscore, but because of the way you are sizing your array: you limited the elements to six characters, and the elements with underscores are the only ones that run over that length; the other four strings require only five `char`s, so they fit into the elements of size six.

You should either declare this as an array of pointers, like this

```
char *str_ex[ARRSIZE] = {"aaaa", "bbbb_bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "ffff_ffff", "eeee"};
```

or give your strings more space, like this:

```
char str_ex[10][ARRSIZE] = {"aaaa", "bbbb_bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "ffff_ffff", "eeee"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `str_ex` to be an array of arrays, each subarray being 6 characters, which means the strings can only be 5 character (plus the terminating `'\0'`). You have a couple strings that are longer than 5 characters, which is what the compiler warns about.

Answer (score 1):

The length of each string should be at most ARRSIZE characters, but the string with the underscore is larger.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the wrong dimension.
Try this:

```
char *str_ex[ARRSIZE] = ....
```

This will work because you initialize the array of C strings with static data.

Answer (score 0):

`ARRSIZE` refers to the number of characters allocated for each string. The problem is that `ARRSIZE` is `6`, while both `"bbbb_bbbb"` and `"ffff_ffff"` are longer than six characters. The underscores are irrelevant.